# Selenium 2 Webdriver (Unable to find elemeny by xpath)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried using Firebug's long-form of the xpath and I get the same error. Using the xpath

```
//span[@onclick=\"mainIframeSrc('l_sams_sched.p_group_schedule')
```

I'm able to locate the element and click on "`Schedule Entry`" in Selenium IDE. The problem is when I try to do the same using webdriver in IE.

**HTML snippet:**

```
<div class="node">
<img alt="Schedule Entry" src="/csui/leaf.gif">
<span class="node-text" onmouseout="this.className='node-text'" onmouseover="this.className='node-text-over'" onclick="mainIframeSrc('l_sams_sched.p_group_schedule')">Schedule Entry</span>
</div>
```

**Webdriver code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@onclick=\"mainIframeSrc('l_sams_sched.p_group_schedule')\"]")).click();
```

**Error:**

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   by xpath using
>   "//span[@onclick="mainIframeSrc('l_sams_sched.p_group_schedule')"]"
>   (7)
>       System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_19'
>       Driver info: driver.version: ie
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.ErrorHandler.verifyErrorCode(ErrorHandler.java:36)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.Finder.handleErrorCode(Finder.java:219)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.Finder.findElementByXPath(Finder.java:183)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.By$6.findElement(By.java:205)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.Finder.findElement(Finder.java:207)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.findElement(InternetExplorerDriver.java:322)
>         at com.eviltester.seleniumtutorials.SAMSLogin.firstPageContainsQAANet(SAMSLogin.java:105)
>         at com.eviltester.seleniumtutorials.SAMSLogin.main(SAMSLogin.java:22)
>       Test failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.node>span.node-text"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in your page an **element with id="tags"** before the element you try to access in MSIE ? If yes, you have to rename it - see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1500 fro more.

Ahh, and one more possible cause is the **security setting** - see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver - look for "Required Configuration".